# Making an arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to make an arduino but for me there is one problem no one sells Atmega 326 controller near by me .
Can i use ATMEGA32L OR ATMEGA8A-PU DIP-28 instead of ATmega168 or 328 chip to build Arduino?

Comment: From site's FAQ. "This site is not a shopping or buying recommendation(s)."

Check the common US, CA, UK, and IT electronics stores to see if they ship international. Most will.

Comment: @rdivilbiss, I don't think the question is inherently a shopping question, but rather asking if any of the microcontrollers he listed are viable substitutes to be used for the arduino platform. The question definitely needs work but it could be turned into a nice lesson about how to identify the requirements of a project and making sure the part will fit the need.

Comment: @jonL

I was concerned it would be interpreted as a shopping question and did not want Mohammed Manssour to have any negative issues because of that. I defer to your experience and thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

All sources I can find say they are both compatible.  A quick google for relevant terms turned up a lot of information on the 32L and a couple of decent links on the 8A-PU.

You will need to load the Arduino bootloader onto the chip before it will work with Arduino sketches and the arduino software.   You can do this in a number of ways, but the two most common are probably:

A) Use an AVR programmer.  They cost about $15-$30 and many places sell them.

B) Use another Arduino.  The Arduino program on your computer can command an Arduino to wiggle it's pins in the right sequence.

Either way, you will need to be sure you use the right bootloader (there are several, not all compatible with all chips) and also you may have to adjust fuse settings and other parameters to get a working chip.

Your easiest option is probably to purchase a standard ATMega328 chip with the bootloader pre-loaded.   These chips are also sold by many places online and usually cost less than $5.